# Angular4 Token Auth making 'auth/validate' call

Tags: angular, authentication

I'm trying to get Angular2 Token Auth module to work but having a continuous '401' error on first load.

I have gotten the auth/registration/login to work, however on a fresh reload -every- time someone is not logged in, they get a 401 Error.

Watching the Network log I see that for some reason it makes 2 `validate_token` calls, but no token should exist. The first one succeeds with a `200` response - But the 2nd fails with a `401`. I've compared both and the only difference I see is that the 2nd doesn't have `content-type` header.

My entire service is pretty generic

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Angular2TokenService} from "angular2-token";
import {Subject, Observable} from "rxjs";
import {Response} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  userSignedIn$:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  constructor(public authService:Angular2TokenService) {

    this.authService.validateToken().subscribe(
      res => res.status == 200 ? this.userSignedIn$.next(res.json().success) : this.userSignedIn$.next(false)
    )
  }

  logOutUser():Observable<Response>{

    return this.authService.signOut().map(
      res => {
        this.userSignedIn$.next(false);
        return res;
      }
    );
  }

  registerUser(signUpData:  {email:string, password:string, passwordConfirmation:string}):Observable<Response>{
    return this.authService.registerAccount(signUpData).map(
      res => {
        this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
        return res
      }
    );
  }

  logInUser(signInData: {email:string, password:string}):Observable<Response>{

    return this.authService.signIn(signInData).map(
      res => {
        this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
        return res
      }
    );

  }

}
```

I believe there is something in Angular2-Token that I do not know about that is causing this but I'm unsure. I've checked the back-end and it has no record of any request coming through.

**Failed Request**

GET /auth/validate_token HTTP/1.1
Host: baseUrl
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

**Successful Request**
OPTIONS /auth/validate_token HTTP/1.1
Host: baseUrl
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

It seems like the failed one is making a GET request, thus causing the issue but I have no idea what is invoking this call. Is there a way to see?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so two things...
First, you state that

> "however on a fresh reload -every- time someone is not logged in, they
>   get a 401 Error."

Well, that's the way it's supposed to work. If they're not authenticated, they're going to get a 401. That's what a 401 means - "authentication required".

If you mean just that if the user hits the browser's "reload" button while authenticated, they get a 401, that means that you are losing your credentials on a reload - you'll probably want to store them in local storage.

Secondly, the two-request behavior that you are seeing is [CORS](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) at work (I'm guessing that your back-end is on a different port, not 4200, which makes CORS kick in).

The OPTION request is a negotiation between the browser and the server to see if you are allowed to make the GET request from a CORS point of view. Apparently you are allowed, so the GET proceeds, but gets a 401, because authentication is required.

This "extra" OPTIONS request is not under your control (or Angular's), it's baked into the browser, and that's just how CORS works.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, your assumption is correct. It's port 4200 -> 8080 - It helps a lot because I was completely confused what was invoking the second call. I think I get it, but it provides a weird feeling if the user has never logged in, for it to be validating the token.